# how to round off NSNumber and create a series of number in Object C

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsnumber

May i know how to round up a NSNumber in object C ?

```
for(int i=6; i>=0; i--) 
{
    DayOfDrinks *drinksOnDay = [appDelegate.drinksOnDayArray objectAtIndex:i];

    NSString * dayString= [NSDate stringForDisplayFromDateForChart:drinksOnDay.dateConsumed];

    [dayArray addObject:dayString];//X label for graph the day of drink.

    drinksOnDay.isDetailViewHydrated = NO;

    [drinksOnDay hydrateDetailViewData];

    NSNumber *sdNumber =  drinksOnDay.standardDrinks;
    [sdArray addObject: sdNumber];      
}
```

inside this sdArray are all the numbers like this 2.1, 1.3, 4.7, 3.1, 4.8, 15.1, 7.2;

i need to plot a graph  Y axis so i need a string of whatever is from the NSNumber to show 
a NSString of this {@"0", @"2", @"4", @"6", @"8", @"10", @"12",@"14",@"16"}. as i need to start from zero, i need to determine which is the biggest number value. in this case it will be 15.1 to show 16 in the graph. instead of doing a static labeling, i will like to do a dynamic labeling.

[image]
what you have seen in the graph is static numbering not dynamic.

i'm sorry for missing out the important info.

thanks for all the comments

Comment: Don't understand what you want because I can get what you want mean when you write "round off"

Comment: Also where are you NSNumbers all you show are NSStrings

Comment: You have an input of 7 strings (not numbers) and want an output of 9 values where I do not understand the relation. Please post an example of how someone would go from the first array to the second.

Comment: I agree with gsempe, Mark, and Joe.  You want to round NSNumber, yet your code is only dealing with NSString.  It's also confusing how you go from 7 strings to 9 strings.  Can you rephrase EXACTLY what you are trying to do?  Do you want to know how to parse a string into a number?  Also, what do you mean by "round off" since I only see whole numbers in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit now makes a lot more sense. Here is an example of getting all even numbers from your  0 to your max value in your `NSArray` of `NSNumber`s (assuming all values are positive, could be changed to support negative values by finding minimum float value as well).

```
NSArray *sdArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:2.1],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.3],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.7],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.1],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:4.8],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.1],
                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:7.2],
                    nil];

//Get max value using KVC
float fmax = [[sdArray valueForKeyPath:@"@max.floatValue"] floatValue];

//Ceiling the max value
int imax = (int)ceilf(fmax);

//Odd check to make even by checking right most bit
imax = (imax & 0x1) ? imax + 1 : imax;

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:(imax / 2) + 1];
//Assuming all numbers are positive 
//(should probably just use unsigned int for imax and i)
for(int i = 0; i <= imax; i +=2)
{
    [array addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the math functions in math.h, there's some nice stuff there like

```
extern double round ( double );
extern float roundf ( float );
```

As for the rest of your question you probably have to parse your strings into numbers, perform whatever action you want on them (rounding, sorting, etc) then put them back into strings.